# What ActivityProxyHelper class actually do?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I need help to understand what is going on in the following two classes. The first activity class is the launching activity.

```
public class UnityPlayerNativeActivity
 extends com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity
{

private ActivityProxyObjectHelper _proxyHelper;
protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
{
super.onCreate(paramBundle);
try
{
  this._proxyHelper = new ActivityProxyObjectHelper(this);
  this._proxyHelper.onCreate(paramBundle);
  return;
}
catch (Exception paramBundle)
{
  Log.i("Prime31", "Failed to create proxyHelper: " + paramBundle.getMessage());
}
}

}
```

And the second class is :

```
public class ActivityProxyObjectHelper
{

private Activity _context;
private List<Class<?>> _proxyClasses = new ArrayList();

public ActivityProxyObjectHelper(Activity paramActivity)
{
  this._context = paramActivity;
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
{
for (;;)
{
  try
  {
    localObject1 = this._context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(this._context.getPackageName(), 128).metaData;
    localObject2 = ((Bundle)localObject1).keySet().iterator();
    bool = ((Iterator)localObject2).hasNext();
    if (bool) {
      continue;
    }
  }
  catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException localNameNotFoundException)
  {
    Object localObject1;
    boolean bool;
    String str;
    Log.i("Prime31", "Failed to load meta-data, NameNotFound: " + localNameNotFoundException.getMessage());
    continue;
  }
  catch (NullPointerException localNullPointerException)
  {
    Log.e("Prime31", "Failed to load meta-data, NullPointer: " + localNullPointerException.getMessage());
    continue;
    Object localObject2 = (Class)localNullPointerException.next();
    try
    {
      ((Class)localObject2).getMethod("onCreate", new Class[] { Bundle.class }).invoke(null, new Object[] { paramBundle });
    }
    catch (Exception localException1) {}
    continue;
  }
  if (((Iterator)localObject1).hasNext()) {
    continue;
  }
  return;
  str = (String)((Iterator)localObject2).next();
  }
 }
}
```

I need to understand what is that ActivityProxyObjectHelper class doing initially after the launching activity gets called. What is the purpose of this class? Why it is trying to get metadata? What is localObject1 and localObject2 trying to do?

Comment: It looks completely bizarre. Where did you find this code?

Comment: From a decompiled code of a unity3d game. I guess it uses Prime31UnityActivity.jar as described in here [https://gist.github.com/prime31/0908e6100d7e228f1add]

Comment: You are a Prime31 user?  Really I would just ask this unusual question on the Prime31 forum.

Comment: Nope, I'm not. Actually I don't know what is Prime31. I searched the net and found the link.